AWS CloudWatch Dashboard based on tags
I would like to build a custom dashboard that contains various metrics. The applications are tagged and I want to receive metrics based on this tags. This means, application1 consists of four lambda functions (tag appName: app1), application2 consists of three lambda functions (tag appName: app2), etc. I want to retrieve the sum of all Lambda invocations grouped by the tag appName. Is this possilbe?
